# How to autocomplete in vim based off partial matching via ctags

Tags: vim, ctags, exuberant-ctags

Example:

In a file in another directory I have a function defined by the following:

```
def _generator_function_1(self):
   passs
```

In the file of my current directory, I have typed the following:

```
def test_generI
```

where `I` denotes my cursor position.

I would like to use vim's autocompletion functionality (i.e. via `^n` or `^p`) to autocomplete the function definition to `test_generator_function_1`. Is there a way of configuring vim autocompletion to match not based off full-prefixes? Or, is there a way in ctags to generate tags based off keywords instead of full function definitions?

EDIT: 
To clarify, I am specifically wondering if keyword-based autocompletion exists. I have autocompletion by tags setting up, so if I typed `"_gen"`, then `^n` would complete to give me `"_generator_function_1"`. In my example, however, it is because the string is prefixed by `"test"` that `"test_gener"` as the starting typed word does not lead to any autocomplete suggestions. So I am wondering if this can somehow be made possible.

Comment: You need to include tags in your complete option. Do this with: `set complete+=t`. See `:help 'complete'`

Comment: Including tags for completion are already enabled. I should have clarified. In this case, if I began the text with "_gen" I would be able to complete the string to become "_generator_function_1". It is because I am beginning with "test_gener" that I am not able to autocomplete because I am presuming there are no tags beginning with "test_gener" (although there are those beginning with "_gener". Which is why I am wondering if such keyword-based autocompletion exists.

Comment: As far as I know, fuzzy-search completion is not supported by the default `^n` or `^p` commands. You'll need an external plugin (for example [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe)) to get fuzz-search completion .

Comment: The funny thing is I have been using YCM for years and have just decided to uninstall it thinking that Vim's built-in autocompletion would suffice for most of my needs. This is great to know! I am still wondering if there might be a way of parsing by keywords when generating tags using exuberant-ctags for this matter, or maybe using vim's omni-completion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Vim doesn't have "autocompletion functionality". It only has "completion", not "autocompletion". You need a plugin for "autocompletion".
2. No, there's no way to obtain your desired behavior without some serious vimscripting. See `:help complete-functions`.